# Как можно заменить componentWillMount на constructor в данном случаи?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

import Modal from '../../components/UI/Modal/Modal';
import Aux from '../Aux';

const errorHandler = (WrappedComponent, axios) => {
    return class extends Component {
        state = {
           errorMessage: false,
        }


        componentWillMount  () {
            axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
                this.setState({errorMessage: null})
                console.log(req);
                return req;
            });
            axios.interceptors.response.use(res => res, error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.setState({errorMessage: error})
            });

      }


        closeErrorMessage = () => {
            this.setState({errorMessage: null})
        }


        render () {

            return (

                <Aux>
                        <Modal show={this.state.errorMessage} closePopup={this.closeErrorMessage}>
                            {this.state.errorMessage ?
                             this.state.errorMessage.message : false}
                        </Modal>
                        <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/> 
                </Aux>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

export default errorHandler;